# Screen Locks after exiting TTY

Tags: tty

I seem to have this problem on my laptop, but not any other of my ubuntu machines. After entering tty and then using control-alt-f1 to re
turn back to the gui desktop environment the system will just turn the screen off and lock. I then have to wait a few moments for the system to respond and then enter my password to get back to the gui environment. Anyone know a way to have it return without locking? Thanks.

Ubuntu 16.04 GNOME